Linearly independent Kronecker product construction
I have a question regarding a constructive argument about Kronecker products which came up while trying to solve a more general problem.

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $E \subseteq [n] \times [n]$ with $d^2 \geq |E|$. Can we find vectors $x_1,\dots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that the set $\{x_i \otimes x_j: (i, j) \in E\}$ is linearly independent?

Here is my thought process so far: let
$$X = \bigcup_{(i,j)\in E} \{x_i, x_j\}$$
Intuitively, by the condition $d^2 \geq |E|$ we should always be able to pick the vectors in $X$ to be appropriate basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that the resulting Kronecker products are different basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{d^2}$. However, I struggle to formalize this.
EDIT: As pointed by @ChristianRemling in the comments the above reasoning doesn't work. However, I think it can be salvaged if we assume that the cardinalities of both $N_i = \{j: (i, j) \in E\}$ and $N'_i = \{j: (j, i) \in E\}$ are bounded by $d$ for all $i$. If this is still not sufficient, I am interested in any "reasonable" assumptions that would guarantee existence.

Counterexample: $d=2$, $E={ (1,1), (1,2), (1,3)}$

@ChristianRemling Yeah I guess my construction would not work but I still believe that such $x_i$'s do exist. Maybe an explicit construction is not possible but an existence proof is still fine.

Isn't @ChristianRemling's comment a counterexample showing that the statement isn't true, not just showing that a particular line of reasoning doesn't work?

@LSpice You're right! I have made an edit in the question which I think would permit the initial construction.
